# How to download references to database that a paper includes and all articles that cite the paper?

Tags: citations, reference-managers, google-scholar

I have some papers for which I want to somehow download an easily manipulated (CSV, Excel) list of references and list of papers which cited the given paper.

On Google Scholar, one can see a "Cited By" option, but there is no way to download this list in bulk. Also, there is no option to get the list of references that the paper made. Although one can look at the paper itself for this information, I'd want a way to get these as a CSV or Excel.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Cross-link to related question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/web-service-to-fetch-article-citations (it deals with the "list of references" part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use Web of Science (Thomson Reuter's) database called Cited Reference Searching.  You can download a list of citations, which can be exported as *.csv.  Here is a [link](http://hsl.lib.umn.edu/biomed/help/web-science-science-find-cited-references) showing some of the basic functionalities.

Comment: Of course, this will only capture citations in venues indexed by Web of Science (and therefore almost no computer science conferences).

Comment: This is a good source, I actually came to the same conclusion. The only problem is that the database is missing many papers. This answer is good in and of itself, though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy using [CitationChaser](https://estech.shinyapps.io/citationchaser/). Follow these steps to start chasing:

- In the "Article input" tab, paste a list of article identifiers (e.g. DOIs)
- Check the articles returned are the ones your interested in
- If you want to perform backward citation chasing (which articles did my articles reference?) then proceed to the "References" tab and click "Search for all referenced articles in Lens.org"
- If you want to perform forward citation chasing (which articles have cited my articles?) then proceed to the "Citations" tab and click "Search for all citing articles in Lens.org"

You can download a list in RIS format of your input articles, referenced articles, and citing articles for easy integration with your reference/review management workflow.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it looks like a great ressource for obtaining refernece information.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [RIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIS_%28file_format%29) and [BibTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) are the two standard file formats for moving references around. I store my references [on Citeulike](http://www.citeulike.org/user/mrvaidya/), which allows me to download them in either format -- I usually use BibTeX since I write my papers in LaTeX, but I know [RIS is used to move references from Endnote to Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/support/kb/importing_records_from_endnote).

[ISI Web of Knowledge](https://images.webofknowledge.com/WOK50B6/help/WOK/hs_output_records.html#dsy426-TRS_other_software) and other citation trackers do allow you to export both the citations in a particular paper as well as the papers that cite it in RIS, BibTeX and tab-delimited formats (using RIS column names, oddly enough!), but I don't think Google Scholar has this functionality. You may have access to the Web of Knowledge through your institute's library.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the information, but I'm not sure you understand my question. What I'm asking is: given a paper, can I download a file (CSV preferably) which contains a list of the references made in the paper, as well as other papers which cited that paper?

Comment: Ah, got it! ISI Web of Knowledge/Science will let you do this (I just tried this and it worked, but you may need to export page-by-page). I've updated my answer to reflect this, but Brian P beat me to Web of Science :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such functionality in existing online repositories at the present time. However, depending on your needs, skills and willingness to dedicate your time and efforts to such project, you can consider *writing custom software*, based on [natural language processing (NLP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) approaches, in particular *information extraction*, for parsing papers of interest - individually or in bulk - in order to *extract* their reference list information. I believe that it should be *relatively* easy to write such software, as the semantic complexity of reference list sections is relatively low. Having said that, I see some potential difficulties, related to the quality (consistency) of listed references in terms of content, formatting and publication style.

I think that using such software would be perfectly *legal* and *ethical*, as that part within each paper doesn't really represent an intellectual property or is copyrighted (please correct me, if I'm wrong).