# Adding all entries in bibliography of a research paper automatically other than using Excite and wos

Tags: publications, phd, citations, thesis

Every research paper had a bibliography at the end carrying various earlier research papers, books, web articles, etc. The user has to click on each one separately and then, through Google or Semantic Scholar, find the bibtex or endnote reference and then add it to the citation manager like Mendeley or Endnote. I do not have Web of Science subscription and [the Excite weblink](https://excite.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/) is not working. Is there any working solution for doing the same, which would automatically **add all the entries in the bibliography** of a research paper **in bulk** to citation manager instead of doing it individually?

Comment: What do you mean by "_Excite weblink ... is not working._"?

Comment: If i put the pdf in excite public web service (https://excite.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/excite) , it shows only one link from bibliography where actually there are more than 50 citations.  I am interested in complete list of bibtex or endnote citations mentioned for each entry in bibliography. Is there any other service or tool to do the same ?

Comment: [Retrieving the references in a publication automatically](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/15596/17254) and [Web Service to fetch article citations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/96403/17254) may give some ideas.

Comment: @Vikrant I just tried the excite page, and it worked perfectly - I had to wait a few minutes but after that I could download the list in different formats. I tried several papers.

Comment: I tried an old paper (published in 1976) on excite and it worked fine after waiting a few minutes. Did you wait long enough?